# Как на мобильном браузере (safari) закрыть бесконечно всплывающее окно (alert)?

Tags: javascript, ipad, safari

police-oplata.ru уведомление от мвд вы заблокированы за неоднократное посещение... Просто хотел почитать книжку в pdf.

Comment: Ну и кому тут суть вопроса непонятна? Известная же штука, только я думал, что уже пофиксили везде...

Comment: @Qwertiy Не пофиксили. Я и на мобильном chrome на такое попадал.

Comment: Я даже знал, как для десктопного такое сделать. Но там уже пофиксили.

Comment: Перевести в режим полёта и открыть Сафари, по идее без интернета должно дать закрыть страницу, на крайняк через настройки снести кэш приложения